# Create new task if a multi-choice field equals 'Option A' but not 'Option B'

Tags: javascript, designer-workflow, tasks

I am using SP Designer and would like to create a new task if a multi-choice field equals a particular value.

The multi-choice field has 5 values.  I want the workflow to make a new task only when Option A is selected.  It is possible to select any combination of the 5 values, but this is not important for the task creation.

If 'Option A' is selected in the field, create new item in the Task List.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
If MultiChoiceColumn contains "Option A" 
   Assign New Task and to VIP
```